# Round number Up to next 0.25 in .Net

Tags: c#

How can I round decimal up (not down) to 0.25?

```
1.26 -> 1.50

1.45 -> 1.50

1.15 -> 1.25

1.00 -> 1.00

1.55 -> 1.75

1.77 -> 2.00
```

I have tried following function but no success.

```
Decimal.Round(x * 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven) / 4
```

Comment: "but no success" doesn't tell us what your actual results were... ideally, show a short but complete program that we can experiment with. My guess is that you want `Decimal.Ceiling` instead of `Decimal.Round`, and that's all...

Comment: You mean `Math.Round`?

Comment: @SonerGönül: The `Math.Round(decimal)` method calls `Decimal.Round(decimal)`. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,0a55b51c2764790f

Comment: @Guffa Arrgh, I didn't _even_ realize there is a method called as `Decimal.Round` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`Ceiling` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.ceiling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to round up:

```
Decimal.Ceiling(x * 4m) / 4m
```

Comment: 1.26 * 4 => 5.04, Ceiling(5.04) => 5, 5 / 4 => 1.25 not 1.5   am I missing something?

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz: Yes, you are. Ceiling(5.04) = 6

Comment: Oop I always get confused with floor and ceiling, yep it will be 6. 6 / 4 => 1.5 that's right.